# Relationship doesn't work in Blade view but it does in the controller

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have the following piece of code

```
public function index()
    {
        //
        $leerlingen = DB::table('leerling')->get();

        $leerling = Admin_Leerling::find(1);
        dd($leerling->klas->title);

        return View::make('leerling.index',compact('leerlingen'));
    }
```

Like you can see, I am trying to get the title of my `Klas` in my controller. This is working I'm getting the correct value. But when I delete the `dd($leerling->klas->title);` and try to do the same thing but then in my index.blade.php I get an error.

```
@if(count($leerlingen))
                               @foreach($leerlingen as $leerling)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{{ $leerling->id }}}</td>
                                    <td>{{{ $leerling->voornaamLeerling . ' ' . $leerling->achternaamLeerling }}}</td>
                                    <td>{{{  $leerling->klas->title }}}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="{{ URL::route('admin.leerling.edit',$leerling->id) }} "> <button class="btn btn-blue">Wijzig</button></a>
                                        <a href="#" data-rel="dialog" data-dialog-text="Weet u zeker dat u deze leerling wilt verwijderen?" data-dialog-url="{{ URL::to('admin/leerling/delete',array($leerling->id)) }}"><button  class="btn btn-red">Verwijderen</button></a>
                                        @if($leerling->active == 1)
                                            <a href="{{ URL::to('admin/leerling/activate',array($leerling->id)) }}">  <button class="btn btn-green">Actief</button> </a>
                                        @else
                                        <a  href="{{ URL::to('admin/leerling/activate',array($leerling->id)) }}">   <button  class="btn btn-red"> Niet Actief</button></a>
                                        @endif
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                               @endforeach
                        @endif
```

Can someone help me with this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use in controller probably:

```
$leerlingen = Admin_Leerling::get();
```

or other model name to get your data, if you get data using query builder ( `DB::table('leerling')->get();`), it's not Eloquent object, so relations won't work

Comment: Sorry one little thing. What if I want get leerlingen.  $klas = Admin_Klas::find($id);
  $lijst = $klas->leerlingen(); Does this doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

To get $lijst you can do

```
   $lijst =Admin_Klas::find($id)->leerlingen;
```

Without () to get the relationship , and loop over $lijst in your view

```
   @foreach( $lijst as $li ) {{$li->name}} @endforeach
```